# InvalidOperationException, the calling thread should be STA because

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, invalidoperationexception

I am developping a project in order to manipulate a lot of objects with several modalities (mouse, leapmotion, touch ...). I made it using the MVVM pattern soI have several Views and ViewModels for all the components I will use. To make it easier to develop I chose to have a Canvas component in which I will manipulate Grids. Each Grid can contain any type of object (Shape, Text, Image, Documents...).

To be able to have all modalities linked to my method, I decided to build one listener per modality (1 for the mouse, 1 for the leapmotion...) and make them detect basic gestures (as Click, DoubleClick ...). All the gestures I chose to detect are associate with a method via a Dictionary. Anyway the linking is working as expected as it executes the right method. T o give an example I have the action calling in my mouse listener:

```
if (_leftClickCounter == 1 && _capturedLeft == false)
{
    if (_dic.ContainsKey(Key.OnClick))
    {
        Action<object> action = _dic[Key.OnClick];
        action.Invoke(null);
    }
}
```

Where:

- _dic is my dictionary
- Key an enumeration of gestures (as OnClick, OnDoubleClick ...)
- action the method to execute

In my example the method executed is:

```
public void Add(object sender)
{
    ObjectModel objectModel = new ObjectModel();
    ObjectView objectView = new ObjectView(objectModel);
    this.objectViews.Add(objectView);
}
```

Where sender is just used for test purpose. It remains unused in the method. My execution stops when it tries to instanciate my ObjectView saying:

```
InvalidOperationException
The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this
```

My ObjectView.xaml.cs class is:

```
public partial class ObjectView : UserControl
{
    public ObjectView(ObjectModel obj)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        EventLinker linker = new EventLinker(this.visualBox);
        ObjectViewModel objectVM = new ObjectViewModel(obj, linker);
        this.DataContext = objectVM;
    }
}
```

And its ObjectView.xaml defining the UserControl to use is very basic:

```
<UserControl x:Class="AusyTouchMultimodal_v1.View.ObjectView"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
     mc:Ignorable="d" 
     d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

     <Grid x:Name="visualBox" Background="Blue"/>

</UserControl>
```

I dont have any compilation errors, just this InvalidOperationException. Can someone explain this issue to me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling your actions in ui thread, like this

```
if (_leftClickCounter == 1 && _capturedLeft == false)
{
    if (_dic.ContainsKey(Key.OnClick))
    {
        Action<object> action = _dic[Key.OnClick];
        // action.Invoke(null);         
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( call your action )
    }
}
```

Comment: well it works. but why my application cannot be ran by only one thread if i dont specify any other ones ?

Comment: I think that other threads are actually used. But your controls are in scope of ui thread so any change that you try to make on ui (including properties that were bounded with viewmodel) should be done throught invoking action on ui thread.